# Look for word in string, then write string in excel having the word found in different font

Tags: python, excel, string, python-3.6

I have exported from sql server info concerning a large number of Reports. The excel columns are ReportPath, DataSourceName,DataSetName and Command Text.

Next i created a python script, which converts the xls in a pandas dataframe and looks for certain words in column Command Text of the dataframe. Code:

```
import pandas as pd

FILE = 'C:\\Users\filepath\filename.xlsx'


def xls_to_df(csvfile):
    df = pd.read_excel(csvfile,names =['ReportPath','DataSourceName','DataSetName','Command Text'])
    table = "Customer"
    flt = df[df['Command Text'].str.contains(table,na=False)]
    return flt


res = xls_to_df(FILE)
print(res)
```

What i am trying to achieve is scan the 'Command Text' column which contains sql queries, find certain keywords and highlight them using colours, bold or whatever is possible.

I think pandas is not really needed here, so maybe my effort is not really relevant. Ideally the script would just go through the column, change fonts to the keywords and save the file.

Comment: Can't you use `replace(table,'\bold{'+table+'}')` instead of `contain`? The bold command is just something random, I'm not sure what is the format of your text.

Comment: @anishtain4 this does the job when printing the output in console, but how would i save it in an excel column, keeping the format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you read an excel into Pandas, you can only manipulate the text. Unfortunately excel does not support rich text formatting (bold, italic, colors, etc) as functions. So if you are importing your data to python only to highlight the cells that have that string, you can just do that in excel:
https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4584-excel-conditional-formatting-if-cell-contains-partial-text.html

Comment: this answers the question. I am aware of the excel solution, was playing around with python though. I wonder if it can be done when saving it in some other file e.g .doc

Comment: That is the problem with office package, if you use latex for example, then you can simply use `str.replace()` to add tags to your text and everything will look fine.